# SQL Union in Separate Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a database to enter all my headache and migraine tracking data into. I'm pulling some queries that show counts of different headache severity by month for a certain year. I have one query that gets all headaches by month, another gets headaches under a certain severity, and the last gets headaches over a certain severity. There are two columns I'm using in the database: HeadacheDate and Severity. I'd like to do a query that would have the following columns as output:

```
Month, Count of All Headaches, Count of Headaches under 6 Severity, 
Count of Headaches Over 5 Severity
```

I've made a union query that takes 3 queries and gives me the data I want but I just can't figure out how to do a query that will move the data around to give me the column format I want.

Here are my union queries:

```
SELECT 
    DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(HeadacheDate), -1)) AS 
HeadacheMonth, 
    COUNT(Severity) as SeverityCount 
FROM 
    Headaches
WHERE 
    Severity > 0 AND YEAR(HeadacheDate) = 2013
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(HeadacheDate)

UNION

SELECT 
    DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(HeadacheDate), -1)) AS HeadacheMonth, 
    COUNT(Severity) as SeverityCount 
FROM 
    Headaches
WHERE 
    Severity > 0 AND Severity < 6 AND YEAR(HeadacheDate) = 2013
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(HeadacheDate)

UNION

SELECT 
    DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(HeadacheDate), -1)) AS HeadacheMonth, 
    COUNT(Severity) as SeverityCount 
FROM 
    Headaches
WHERE
    Severity > 5 AND YEAR(HeadacheDate) = 2013
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(HeadacheDate);
```

This returns results something like this:

```
April   3
April   11
April   14
August  5
August  10
August  15
December    2
December    11
December    13
July    5
July    6
July    11
June    4
June    10
June    14
March   1
March   2
March   3
May 5
May 8
May 13
November    1
November    13
November    14
October 4
October 9
October 13
September   4
September   10
September   14
```

What I want is this:

```
Month, Count of All Headaches, Count of Headaches under 6 Severity, Count of Headaches Over 5 Severity

January, 20, 15, 5
February, 18, 13, 5
```

and so on.

I'd also like to include months where one of the count fields could be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional grouping:

```
SELECT 
  [HeadacheMonth]      = DATENAME(month, DateAdd(month , MONTH(HeadacheDate), -1))
 ,[SeverityCountTotal] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Severity > 0 THEN 1 END)
 ,[SeverityCount_1_5]  = COUNT(CASE WHEN Severity > 0 
                                     AND Severity < 6  THEN 1 END)
 ,[SeverityCount_6]    = COUNT(CASE WHEN Severity > 5 THEN 1 END)
FROM Headaches
WHERE YEAR(HeadacheDate) = 2013
GROUP BY MONTH(HeadacheDate);
```

`YEAR(HeadacheDate) = 2013` is not SARGable so if index exits on that column query optimizer will skip it.You could consider using:

```
HeadacheDate >= '2013-01-01T00:00:00' AND HeadacheDate < '2014-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Seeing the new neurologist on Tuesday so I wanted to prepare some reports

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Month
       ,COUNT(Severity) AS ALL
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN Severity<6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SevUn6
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN Severity>5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SevOv5

 FROM <table>
 GROUP BY Month
```